# Spring data redis 2.0.3 LettuceConnectionFactory on cacheManager creates cache key in blank namespace(folder) under mentioned cachebucket

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-redis

I am new to spring data redis. I have used spring boot  data redis 2.0.3 as shown below (from my gradle build)

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis:2.0.3.RELEASE')
compile('io.lettuce:lettuce-core:5.1.3.RELEASE')
```

When I try to create create(PUT) or get(GET), it noticed in Redis Desktop manager that , the key are crated in the mentioned bucket but in a blank namespace(folder) under bucket. But I want to create the cache keys under the bucket(namespace) only but not in blank subfolder like another empty namespace(folder - from I could see from Redis Desktop manager)

```
@Bean
LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceClientConfigurationConnectionFactory() {
    RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setHostName(redisHostName);
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPort(redisPort);
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPassword(RedisPassword.of(redisAuth));
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setDatabase(0);

    LettuceClientConfiguration.LettuceClientConfigurationBuilder lettuceClientConfiguration = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder();

    lettuceClientConfiguration.useSsl();

    LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConFactory = new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration,
            lettuceClientConfiguration.build());

    return lettuceConFactory;
}

@Bean
public RedisCacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration() {
    RedisSerializer genericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer = new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer();
    RedisSerializer stringRedisSerializer = new StringRedisSerializer();

    RedisCacheConfiguration redisCacheConfiguration = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
            .disableCachingNullValues()
            .entryTtl(Duration.ofHours(1))
            .serializeKeysWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(stringRedisSerializer))
            .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(genericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer));
    redisCacheConfiguration.usePrefix();
    return redisCacheConfiguration;
}

@Bean
@Primary
public CacheManager  initRedisCacheManager(LettuceConnectionFactory factory) {

    RedisCacheManager.RedisCacheManagerBuilder builder = RedisCacheManager
            .RedisCacheManagerBuilder.fromConnectionFactory(factory);
    builder.cacheDefaults(cacheConfiguration());
    builder.transactionAware();
    RedisCacheManager cacheManager = builder.build();
    cacheManager.afterPropertiesSet();
    return cacheManager;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could fix the problem by making sure , the prefixKyesWith is set per each cache bucket so put and get operations look for the correct place to store/read.

/**
     * gets redis cache writer
     * @return RedisCacheWriter
     */
    @Bean
    RedisCacheWriter redisCacheWriter() {
        return RedisCacheWriter.lockingRedisCacheWriter(lettuceClientConfigurationConnectionFactory());
    }

/**
     * gets cache manager
     * @return CacheManager
     */
    @Bean
    @Primary
    CacheManager cacheManager() {
        RedisSerializer genericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer = new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer();
        Map cacheNamesConfigurationMap = new HashMap<>();

```
    // configure catch buckets with prefixKeysWith information
    cacheNamesConfigurationMap.put(CacheBucket.A, RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig().prefixKeysWith(CacheBucket.A+":")
            .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(genericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer)));
    cacheNamesConfigurationMap.put(CacheBucket.B, RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig().prefixKeysWith(CacheBucket.B+":")
            .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(genericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer)));
    cacheNamesConfigurationMap.put(CacheBucket.D, RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig().prefixKeysWith(CacheBucket.D+":")
            .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(genericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer)));
    cacheNamesConfigurationMap.put(CacheBucket.E, RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig().prefixKeysWith(CacheBucket.E+":")
            .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(genericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer)));
    cacheNamesConfigurationMap.put(CacheBucket.F, RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig().prefixKeysWith(CacheBucket.F+":")
            .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(genericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer)));

    RedisCacheManager cacheManager =  new RedisCacheManager(redisCacheWriter(), cacheConfiguration(), cacheNamesConfigurationMap);
    cacheManager.setTransactionAware(true);
    cacheManager.afterPropertiesSet();
    return cacheManager;
}
```